# Android Studio : com.android.volley.TimeoutError. What happen?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

Everytime I change the spinner value the log said TimeoutError.

This is the volley:

```
val q = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
            val url = "http://10.2.2.2/donasiku/perbandingan.php"
            val sr = object:StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,Response.Listener {
                val array = JSONArray("needs")
                var obj = array.getJSONObject(0)
                textViewJumlahKebutuhan.text = obj.getString("nilai")

            },Response.ErrorListener {
                    response-> Log.i("error : ", response.toString())
            })
            {
                override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                    var id = index+1;
                    val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                    params.put("idkebutuhan",id.toString())
                    return params

                }
            }

            q.add(sr)
```

And then I call the function inside the onItemSelected override function,
and this is my php file :

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","donasiku");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM kebutuhan";
    $needs = array();
    $i=0;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $needs[$i]['id'] = $obj['id'];
        $needs[$i]['nilai'] = $obj['nilai'];

        $kebutuhanid = $needs[$i]['id'];

        $sql2 ="SELECT nilai FROM detaildonasi WHERE kebutuhan_id = '$kebutuhanid'";
        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

        if($result2->num_rows > 0)
        {
            $sql3 = "SELECT SUM(nilai) AS donated FROM detaildonasi WHERE kebutuhan_id = '$kebutuhanid'";
            $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);

            while($obj3 = $result3->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $needs[$i]['nilaidonasi'] = $obj3['donated'];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $needs[$i]['nilaidonasi'] = 0;
        }

        $i++;
    }   
    echo json_encode($needs);
    $conn->close();
```

I think the error is in the Volley but I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Your error showing the connectivity issue, which could be due to any reason like API is taking time(any long running query) or firewall is blocking your request; resulting in breach of timeout period.

Try **RetryPolicy** for your request.

Comment: Are you sure that your local server is started?

Comment: yes it has started